# Change maxZoom option in runtime to ol.View in angular-openlayers-directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, openlayers-3, angular-openlayers

I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36865516/change-maxzoom-option-in-runtime-to-ol-view-in-openlayers-3/36865905#36865905) to change maxZoom in runtime using openlayers3 and that works perfect:

```
map.setView(new ol.View({
  zoom: 10,
  maxZoom: 17,
  minZoom: 10,
}));
```

However, im trying to integrate this solution using the [angular-openlayers-directive](https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-openlayers-directive) and the map is disappearing. Here a [**Plunker demo failing**](http://plnkr.co/edit/sj8RDA0B6dWVeG784AD9?p=preview). I tried creating new directive and also didn't work.

```
olData.getMap().then(function(map){
  map.setView(new ol.View({
    zoom: 11,
    maxZoom: 11,
    minZoom: 0,
  }));
});
```

Any suggestions on how to integrate this and if you could make it work in the Plunker demo would be great.

Comment: Maybe you find here what you need [tombatossals/angular-openlayers-directive/examples](http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-openlayers-directive/examples/023-center-constrain-zoom-example.html)

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation of `ol.View` object

> http://openlayers.org/en/v3.2.1/apidoc/ol.View.html

If center option is not given while creating `ol.View` object it is taken as `undefined`. If its `undefined` then layer sources will not be fetched..In `$scope.changeZoom()` method center was undefined since it was not provided while creating. Because of this map object was not loaded correctly.

**Fix**

```
olData.getMap().then(function(map){
   map.setView(new ol.View({
      center: ol.proj.transform([37.41, 8.82], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
      zoom: 11,
      maxZoom: 11,
      minZoom: 0,
   }));
});
```

I have given some random coordinates as center.
See the working plunk code [**here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/OYYP0jzT5BTnCEKT7oUk?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why they aren't the same (I didn't investigate the ordinary ol3 solution you stated) but after stepping through the ol-debug.js code it seems it's drawing a blank frame because the new view doesn't have a center.

You can set the center using the existing view's center:

```
$scope.changeZoom = function () {
    olData.getMap().then(function (map) {
        newView = new ol.View({
            zoom: 5,
            maxZoom: 20,
            minZoom: 0,
        });
        newView.setCenter(map.getView().getCenter());
        map.setView(newView);
    });
};
```

And here's a [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/n3787r7JX6Ftp1lzKLgB?p=preview)*.

*I haven't used plunker before this so if it doesn't work let me know and I'll try again!